# titleformat with hang writes it in two lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, titlesec

I can't find a way for the tikz code of the section text to be written after the section number. I appreciate any help

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
%----------------------------------
\usepackage[x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

\newcommand{\caja} [1]{%

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[fill=brown!20!, text width=.5\linewidth] (m) {#1};

\draw[rounded corners, line width=.5pt, lime] 
(m.north west)--(m.north east)--(m.south east);

\draw[rounded corners, line width=1pt, green] 
([yshift=3pt]m.north west)--([yshift=3pt, xshift=3pt]m.north east)--([xshift=3pt]m.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}%

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\large}{\footnotesize SECCIÓN \thesection. }{3pt}{\caja}

\section{Prueba}

\end{document}
```

An image of what my code does and that is not what I want, I want it on one line and following the section number

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Remove the empty line at the beginning of the definition of `\caja`. That creates the line break.